# How to take object from BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class `X`, class`Machine`, class `Z`, all of them are Threads. When `Machine` threads are initialized, they are put on a `BlockingQueue firstQueue`. Inside machines' run method there is a while loop which checks if its boolean variable should be true or false. When it is true, machine should be put on `BlockingQueue secondQueue`

```
secondQueue.put(this);
```

and `Z` class can take it from there. If machine thread returns false, class `X` can take machine from `firstQueue` and work on it.
Now, my question is: when boolean is true, is it possible to make `Machine` take itself from `firstQueue`?
PS.I know that the question might be unclearly asked, but I don't know how to form it properly. If anyone knows to make it better, please correct it.

EDIT.
Code samples.
Here is a part from class that starts all the threads, all the queues are initialized of course.

```
public class Machine implements Runnable{
private final BlockingQueue firstQueue;
private final BlockingQueue secondQueue;
boolean broken;

public Machine(...){...}


 public void run() {

    while(true){
            //use Rand (min=0, max=1) and define if(random==1)broken=true else broken=false

            if(broken==true){
                Machine multi = fistQueue.take(this);//here is problem!!!!!
                secondQueue.put(this);
            }  
     }
}...}
```

and part form class that starts the threads

```
//machines should have an ability to take themselves from queue when broken==true, and then put on secondQueue
BlockingQueue<Machine> firstQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Machine>(10);
    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(int k=0; k < 10; k++){
        Machine M= new Machine(secondQueue, k);
        firstQueue.add(M);
        service.submit(M);
    }

 //X can take machines from firstQueue, and work on them if broken==false
Thread XThread = new Thread(new X(firstQueue));
    XThread.start();

//takes machines form secondQueue
    Thread ZThread = new Thread(new Z(secondQueue));
    ZThread.start();
```

EDIT2

```
public class X implements Runnable(){

//fields, constructor

public void run() {

    while(true){
            machine=machines.take();
            if(machine.broken==true){
                //leave this machine (it should be on , and take other which is fine_
            } 
            while(machine.broken==false){
                machine.pass(record); // (Record record=new Record(task, result field);
               //do Your thing
           }
           if(result==initialResultFromX){
              //means it got broken while working and needs to take a new machine
             }
}...
}
```

Comment: easier if you put relevent code

Comment: Why cant you check the state of the boolean first and then put the machine object to appropriate queue?

Comment: In principle yes, because class `BlockingQueue` has a `remove(Object o)` method that can remove an object from the queue, wherever it is in the queue. Whether this design is a good idea is another question.

Comment: Looks to me that you are complicating things unnecessarily.  You can use a Executor service (FixedPool) and solve this. The advantage of using executor service is you don't need to expose Blocking Queue implementations. Please also provide sample code if you want accurate answers.

Comment: @Jesper I can't remove them, they need to be there

Comment: Is setting the broken-state randomly all that `run()` does? Why is it infinite? Why don't you have X check Machine's state and relay them to secondQueue if "broken"?

Comment: 1.Yes, checking if it is broken is all run does. However. `Machine` has has a method to found simple equation given by X class. 2.My teacher wants the program to run infinitely. 3.It is a good idea. But if `Machine` brake during doing math, how to return equation to X, and let it choose other machine?

Comment: Aaaaahhhh, so you are trying to simulate a Machine possibly braking at "any time" during process... This changes everything. Maybe you could throw an exception when braking ... Could you also post some of the X-Code ? The interaction between X and Machine is key to your desired answer, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, this answer aims to help improve the design of the solution, which in turn might answer the actual question. However, if OP is happy with the current design, I believe the question can be answered by removing the following line:

```
Machine multi = fistQueue.take(this);
```

So,

> Is it possible to make Machine take itself from firstQueue?

There is no method to directly get an object inside the queue without removing it (As stated in the comments, the machine should not be removed from the first queue). Because you can access the instance of the machine by using `this`, `secondQueue.put(this)` would suffice in adding the `Machine` to the second queue.

I might be interpreting your design wrong, but it seems to me that each `Machine` has a state. This state depends whether or not the `Machine` can or cannot execute whatever it must execute. If this is true, I believe it isn't wise to keep the handling of state changes in the machine itself(adding/removing itself to different executing queues).

You need an abstraction of some sort. Lets called this your `StateMachine`. The `StateMachine` creates, manages and handles state changes of each `Machine`, by implementing some listening interface. This will allow each machine to report any events or problems to the `StateMachine`. The `StateMachine` can then determine how to handle events.

I'll try to explain by example. Here is the interface that the `StateMachine` will implement:

```
public interface BrokenListener {
    public void onBrokenEvent(Object machine);
}
```

This allows communications between the `StateMachine` and each `Machine`. However, this requires an instance of the `StateMachine` to be passed to each machine **instead of** the queues.

```
for(int k=0; k < 10; k++){
    Machine m = new Machine(this); //where this is the StateMachine
    firstQueue.add(m);
}
```

Once a `Machines` state changes from `broken == false` to `broken == true`, the `onBrokenEvent()` can be called.

```
public class Machine {
    /* The listener */
    private BrokenListener listener;
    private boolean broken = false;

    public Machine(BrokenListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    /* When the state of the machine changes */
    public void setBroken(boolean broken) {
        this.broken = broken;
        if (this.broken) {
            //Here we pass the current Machine to the StateMachine. How the event is handled should not be up to the machine.
            this.listener.onBrokenEvent(this);                
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `StateMachine`:

```
public class StateMachine implements BrokenListener {
    @Override
    public void onBrokenEvent(Object machine) {
        if (machine instanceof Machine) {
            second.add((Machine) machine);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the state machine implements the `onBrokenEvent` method. When this method is called by the `Machine`, it can be added to the second queue for processing.

I assume the `X` and `Y` classes will do the processing, so you still need to pass the queues to them.

```
Thread XThread = new Thread(new X(firstQueue));
XThread.start();

Thread ZThread = new Thread(new Z(secondQueue));
ZThread.start();
```

What makes this nice is, it keeps the logic used for handling state changes out of the `Machine`.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer. I know it might be noob question but could explain me why to use such syntax: `this.broken = broken` in method setBroken?

Comment: I assumed that you have a setter method for the variable `broken`. In your example, how does the `boolean` variable `broken` change from uninitialized to `true`? I also edited the first part of my answer.

Comment: It changes randomly. I have a method that gives me random number, then in run I am checkin if this number is equal to a number I have chosen to represent "if machine is broken" if yes, then it sets broken variable to true and all the magic with queues, and now listener, should appear. There is no error after compilation, but machines don't break at all even though the chances . Is there something wrong with this declaration: in class that starts thread in for loop `static StateMachine state`, then in main `state=new StateMachine(second);` and `Machine M= newMachine(state, k, listener, second)`

Comment: I know You told me not to put queue inside new Machine, but how can I call `StateMachine` inside `Machine` without it?

Comment: So the run method not only checks, but determines whether or not the machine is broken? What you need to do is call `this.listener.onBrokenEvent(this)` as soon as the machine is classified as broken. `this` refers to the current instance of machine. Thus, when `onBrokenEvent(this)` is called, you let the `StateMachine` know which `Machine` is broken by passing it `this`. And you should pass the `StateMachine` as the listener, eg `BrokenListener listener = new StateMachine(first, second)`, `new Machine(k, listener)`